# Sed replace pattern with line number

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

I need to replace the pattern `###` with the current line number.

I managed to Print in the next line with both AWK and SED.

`sed -n "/###/{p;=;}" file` prints to the next line, without the `p;`, it replaces the whole line.

`sed -e "s/###/{=;}/g" file` used to make sense in my head, since the `=;` returns the line number of the matched pattern, but it will return me the the text `{=;}`

What am i Missing? I know this is a silly question. I couldn't find the answer to this question in the sed manual, it's not quite clear.

If possible, point me what was i missing, and what to make it work. Thank you

Comment: [`Since the "=" command only prints to standard output, you cannot print the line number on the same line as the pattern.`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-48)

Comment: Is it possible with Awk?

Comment: I tested every answer, and the one that worked better was @twalberg 's awk. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple `awk` oneliner:

```
awk '{gsub("###",NR,$0);print}'
```

Comment: @Thor Maybe I'm making different assumptions - doesn't that just put the line number at the beginning of the line? I read the OP to mean that "###" might be anywhere in the line, hence the `gsub()`. Although on 2nd reading, it does seem having the number at beginning of line might be what's in mind...

Answer (score 5):

Given [the limitations of the `=` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-48), I think it's easier to divide the job in two (actually, three) parts. With GNU `sed` you can do:

```
$ sed -n '/###/=' test > lineno
```

and then something like

```
$ sed -e '/###/R lineno' test | sed '/###/{:r;N;s/###\([^\n]*\n\)\([^\n]*\)/\2\1/;tr;:c;s/\n\n/\n/;tc}'
```

I'm afraid there's no simple way with `sed` because, as well as the `=` command, the `r` and GNU extension `R` commands don't read files into the pattern space, but rather directly append the lines to the output, so the contents of the file cannot be modified in any way. Hence piping to another `sed` command.

If the contents of `test` are

```
fooo
bar ### aa
test
zz ### bar
```

the above will produce

```
fooo
bar 2 aa
test
zz 4 bar
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed = file | sed 'N;:a;s/\(\(.*\)\n.*\)###/\1\2/;ta;s/.*\n//'
```

An alternative using cat:

```
cat -n file | sed -E ':a;s/^(\s*(\S*)\t.*)###/\1\2/;ta;s/.*\t//'
```

Comment: Can you explain the sed pattern ?

Answer (score 3):

As noted by *Lev Levitsky* this isn't possible with one invocation of sed, because the line number is sent directly to standard out.

You could have sed write a sed-script for you, and do the replacement in two passes:

*infile*

```
a
b
c
d
e
###
###
###
a
b
###
c
d
e
###
```

Find the lines that contain the pattern:

```
sed -n '/###/=' infile
```

Output:

```
6
7
8
11
15
```

Pipe that into a sed-script writing a new sed-script:

```
sed 's:.*:&s/###/&/:'
```

Output:

```
6s/###/6/
7s/###/7/
8s/###/8/
11s/###/11/
15s/###/15/
```

Execute:

```
sed -n '/###/=' infile | sed 's:.*:&s/^/& \&/:' | sed -f - infile
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
6
7
8
a
b
11
c
d
e
15
```

Answer (score 1):

is this ok ?

```
kent$  echo "a
b
c
d
e"|awk '/d/{$0=$0" "NR}1'
a
b
c
d 4
e
```

if match pattern "d", append line number at the end of the line.

**edit**

oh, you want to replace the pattern not append the line number... take a look the new cmd:

```
kent$  echo "a
b
c
d
e"|awk '/d/{gsub(/d/,NR)}1'
a
b
c
4
e
```

and the line could be written like this as well:  `awk '1+gsub(/d/,NR)' file`

Comment: The OP needs to substitute the pattern with line number, this is not exactly the answer.

Answer (score 1):

one-liner to modify the FILE in place, replacing LINE with the corresponding line number:

```
seq 1 `wc -l FILE | awk '{print $1}'` | xargs -IX sed -i 'X s/LINE/X/' FILE
```

Comment: for osx version of sed I had to modify this as the `-i` param is treated differently https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854797/29924

Answer (score 0):

Following on from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519367/29924

If you try this on osx the version of sed is different and you need to do:

```
seq 1 `wc -l FILE | awk '{print $1}'` | xargs --verbose -IX sed -i bak "X s/__line__/X/" FILE
```

see https://markhneedham.com/blog/2011/01/14/sed-sed-1-invalid-command-code-r-on-mac-os-x/