# Replace repeated elements in a list with unique identifiers

Tags: bash, replace, sed, rename

I have a list like the below:

```
1 . Fred 1 6 78 8 09
1 1 Geni 1 4 68 9 34
2 . Sam 3 4 56 6 89
3 . Flit 2 4 56 8 34
3 4 Dog 2 5 67 8 78
3 . Pig 2 5 67 2 21
```

(except the real list is 40 million lines long).

There are repeated elements in the second column (i.e. the ".")

I want to replace these with unique identifers (e.g. ".1", ".2", ".3"...".*n*")

I tried to do this with a bash loop / sed combination, but it didn't work...

Failed attempt:

```
for i in 1..4
  do
    sed -i "s_//._//."$i"_"$i""
  done
```

(Essentially, I was trying to get sed to replace each *n* th "." with ".*n*", but this didn't work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `awk` (assuming your file is called `input`:

```
$ awk '$2=="."{$2="."++counter}{print}' input 
1 .1 Fred 1 6 78 8 09
1 1 Geni 1 4 68 9 34
2 .2 Sam 3 4 56 6 89
3 .3 Flit 2 4 56 8 34
3 4 Dog 2 5 67 8 78
3 .4 Pig 2 5 67 2 21
```

The `awk` program replaces the second column (`$2`) by a string formed by concatenating `.` and a pre-incremented counter (`++counter`) if the second column was exactly `.`. It then prints out all the columns it got (with `$2` modified or not) (`{print}`).

Plain bash alternative:

```
c=1
while read -r a b line ; do
  if [ "$b" == "." ] ; then
    echo "$a ."$((c++))" $line"
  else
    echo "$a $b $line"
  fi
done < input
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do this with `sed` . Some of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496717/sed-replace-pattern-with-line-number) might help though.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged `sed` and `bash`, here are a few examples for completeness.

**Bash only**

Use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The second column will be unique, but not sequential:

```
i=1; while read line; do echo ${line/\./.$((i++))}; done < input

1 .1 Fred 1 6 78 8 09
1 1 Geni 1 4 68 9 34
2 .3 Sam 3 4 56 6 89
3 .4 Flit 2 4 56 8 34
3 4 Dog 2 5 67 8 78
3 .6 Pig 2 5 67 2 21
```

**Bash + sed**

`sed` cannot increment variables, it has to be done externally.

For each line, increment `$i` if line contains a `.`, then let `sed` append `$i` after the `.`

```
i=0                                    
while read line; do                 
    [[ $line == *.* ]] && i=$((i+1))   
    sed "s#\.#.$i#" <<<"$line" 
done < input
```

Output:

```
1 .1 Fred 1 6 78 8 09
1 1 Geni 1 4 68 9 34
2 .2 Sam 3 4 56 6 89
3 .3 Flit 2 4 56 8 34
3 4 Dog 2 5 67 8 78
3 .4 Pig 2 5 67 2 21
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
awk '{gsub(/\./,c++);print}' filename
```

Output:

```
1 0 Fred 1 6 78 8 09
1 1 Geni 1 4 68 9 34
2 2 Sam 3 4 56 6 89
3 3 Flit 2 4 56 8 34
3 4 Dog 2 5 67 8 78
3 5 Pig 2 5 67 2 21
```