# Awk or Bash, Replacing string from specific column and line number to foreward

Tags: awk

I want to substituted capital letter B with C in column 5 and from line 6 to the end of the file, need to keep the spaces as it is from my original input file as it is.

```
ATOM   1939  HG2 PRO A 125      35.681  32.906  38.437  1.00 43.59           H  
ATOM   1940  HG3 PRO A 125      34.593  33.765  37.652  1.00 41.79           H  
ATOM   1941  HD2 PRO A 125      37.364  34.075  37.624  1.00 43.38           H  
ATOM   1942  HD3 PRO A 125      36.333  34.312  36.415  1.00 41.29           H  
TER   
ATOM   1944  N   MET B  11      16.583  29.975  -4.306  1.00 51.32           N  
ATOM   1945  CA  MET B  11      15.542  30.263  -3.327  1.00 39.92           C  
ATOM   1946  C   MET B  11      16.146  30.366  -1.933  1.00 32.50           C
```

I have read:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486840/replace-a-string-with-sed-from-specific-lines
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70878/replacing-string-based-on-line-number
3. [Sed replace pattern with line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496717/sed-replace-pattern-with-line-number)

and my attempt is: `awk 'NR == 6 && $ == 5, { sub(" B ", " C ") }'`

Comment: `NR == 6` should be `NR >= 6`. What do you expect `$ == 5` to mean? `$` has to be followed by a number to refer to the contents of that column.

Comment: @Barmar with `$` I tried to specify the column position

Comment: You do that by putting `$5` in the `sub()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple `awk` should help you in same. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk '
FNR>=6 && match($0,/^(\S+[[:space:]]+)(\S+[[:space:]]+)(\S+[[:space:]]+)(\S+[[:space:]]+)(\S+)(.*)$/,arr) && arr[5]=="B"{
  $0=arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4] "C" arr[6]
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Using `match` function here to keep your spaces as it is even after substitution.

Comment: Thank you. But, how can I specify the condition with column 5?

Comment: @Another.Chemist, yes please we need to give it in `sub` function itself.

Comment: @Another.Chemist, Please try my updated code once, this will keep the spaces as it is, please do test it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have tested and it promps me: `awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,`

Comment: @Another.Chemist, It works fine for me and tested it successfully. Could you please make sure its properly copied, I re-tested it now and it works fine.

Comment: @Another.Chemist, also this requires GNU `awk`, so you can check your `awk`'s version by doing a:`awk --version` also.

Comment: it promps me `awk: not an option: --version`

Comment: @Another.Chemist, ohhhh may be you are using old `awk`. Do a `which awk` once and let me know. Also on another note: If possible can you update awk to latest if yes then do it to GNU `awk`. Let me know.

Comment: I have the last version of `mawk`

Comment: @Another.Chemist, oh ok, not sure if `mawk` supports match funcition's 3rd argument or not. Is it Sun OS you are having?

Comment: I installed `gawk` and it worked ! Thank you !!!

Comment: @Another.Chemist, I have updated your question a bit for keeping the spaces same thing, to make sure all are on same page, cheers.

Comment: I like how you write _This simple awk_ ...

Comment: @kvantour, initially it was simple(this one is also simple only :) ) but then to preserve spaces/tabs etc edited it, that was kept there as it is.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : since you're using a `gawk`-specific solution, why not group all of `$1-$4` into 1 array cell, `$5` standalone, then rest of the line in 3rd cell ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any `awk` and preserve the format by using a `sub()` on the entire record. This prevents `awk` from recalculating the fields. For instance, you can do:

```bash
awk 'NR > 5 { sub(/MET B/,"MET C") }1' file
```

Here `awk` will replace the first occurrence of `"MET B"` with `"MET C"` beginning with the 6th record leaving the spacing alone.

**Output**

```
ATOM   1939  HG2 PRO A 125      35.681  32.906  38.437  1.00 43.59           H
ATOM   1940  HG3 PRO A 125      34.593  33.765  37.652  1.00 41.79           H
ATOM   1941  HD2 PRO A 125      37.364  34.075  37.624  1.00 43.38           H
ATOM   1942  HD3 PRO A 125      36.333  34.312  36.415  1.00 41.29           H
TER
ATOM   1944  N   MET C  11      16.583  29.975  -4.306  1.00 51.32           N
ATOM   1945  CA  MET C  11      15.542  30.263  -3.327  1.00 39.92           C
ATOM   1946  C   MET C  11      16.146  30.366  -1.933  1.00 32.50           C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NR >= 6` to update all lines starting with line 6. Your code does it on line 6 only.

Put `$5` in the `sub()` call to make the substitution only in that field.

```
awk 'NR >= 6 {sub("B", "C", $5)} 1'
```

I hope you don't care about the number of spaces between the columns. The line that are updated will have multiple spaces collapsed into one, so

```
ATOM   1944  N   MET B  11      16.583  29.975  -4.306  1.00 51.32           N
```

becomes

```
ATOM 1944 N MET C 11 16.583 29.975 -4.306 1.00 51.32 N
```

Comment: Thank you. But the format is broken

Comment: How the format can be conserved?

Comment: Instead of just printing the line with `1`, you can write code that prints the formatted line with `printf()`. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, it's not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of `gawk`, you could use [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) which will have a `seps` array that stores the separators.

You can split on the field separator `FS`, and then use the number returned by split to loop through all the fields.

When encountering field 5 and the value is `B`, then change it to `C`

```
awk 'NR > 5 {
  nr = split($0, a, FS, seps)
  for (i = 1; i <= nr; ++i) {
    if (i == 5 && a[i] == "B") a[i] = "C" 
    printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]
  }
  printf "\n"
  next
}1' file
```

Output

```
ATOM   1939  HG2 PRO A 125      35.681  32.906  38.437  1.00 43.59           H
ATOM   1940  HG3 PRO A 125      34.593  33.765  37.652  1.00 41.79           H
ATOM   1941  HD2 PRO A 125      37.364  34.075  37.624  1.00 43.38           H
ATOM   1942  HD3 PRO A 125      36.333  34.312  36.415  1.00 41.29           H
TER
ATOM   1944  N   MET C  11      16.583  29.975  -4.306  1.00 51.32           N
ATOM   1945  CA  MET C  11      15.542  30.263  -3.327  1.00 39.92           C
ATOM   1946  C   MET C  11      16.146  30.366  -1.933  1.00 32.50           C
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to preserve all the spaces and tabs you like without using vendor-proprietary solutions :

> ```
>  mawk 'BEGIN {   _ = length(FS="[ \t]+") } NR<_ || NF<_ ||
>               $!NF = sprintf("%.*sC%s", (__ = index($!_,
>                              $_))- !!_, $!_, substr($!_, ++__))'
> ```

```
ATOM   1939  HG2 PRO A 125      35.681  32.906  38.437  1.00 43.59           H  
ATOM   1940  HG3 PRO A 125      34.593  33.765  37.652  1.00 41.79           H  
ATOM   1941  HD2 PRO A 125      37.364  34.075  37.624  1.00 43.38           H  
ATOM   1942  HD3 PRO A 125      36.333  34.312  36.415  1.00 41.29           H  
TER   
ATOM   1944  N   MET C  11      16.583  29.975  -4.306  1.00 51.32           N  
ATOM   1945  CA  MET C  11      15.542  30.263  -3.327  1.00 39.92           C  
ATOM   1946  C   MET C  11      16.146  30.366  -1.933  1.00 32.50           C
```